# Pythonic way to create list of prefixes in single line code

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Given:** a list, for example `[1,2,"hello","world"]`

**Need to:** create list of lists with all the prefixes, 
for example the output will be: `[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, "hello"],  [1, 2, "hello", "world"]]`

**Problem:** the function body must contain only single line code.

I don't have any problem to do this with regular way (loops, etc..) but cant figure out how to do only with single line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `range` to iterate indexes within list comprehension and use slicing to create the prefixes:

```
>>> l = [1,2,"hello","world"]
>>> [l[:i] for i in range(len(l) + 1)]
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 'hello'], [1, 2, 'hello', 'world']]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have totally forgot about slicing.